# Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript

```
var url = "C:\xampp\htdocs\wcf2\wcf/attachments/5d/18-5dffacdfe6d2cf1db8dfabbb5b53ae8dc65bd325";
```

results in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. Is there any way to fix it in javascript or do I need to escape it before in PHP?

Edit: My script looks like this:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    thingiurlbase = "{@$__wcf->getPath('td')}js";
    thingiview = new Thingiview("viewer");
    thingiview.setObjectColor('#C0D8F0');

    thingiview.initScene();
    var url = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\\wcf2\\wcf/attachments/5d/18-5dffacdfe6d2cf1db8dfabbb5b53ae8dc65bd325";
    thingiview.loadSTL(url); 
    thingiview.setRotation(false);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try double instead of single backslashes in the URL.

Comment: could you provide bit more error details?

Comment: are you printing the string from PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash characters.

```
var url = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wcf2\\wcf/attachments/5d/18-5dffacdfe6d2cf1db8dfabbb5b53ae8dc65bd325";
```

Otherwise, JavaScript tries to interpret `\x`, `\h`, and `\w` as escaped special characters.

In this particular case, though, it looks like you could just replace the `\` with `/` instead:

```
var url = "C:/xampp/htdocs/wcf2/wcf/attachments/5d/18-5dffacdfe6d2cf1db8dfabbb5b53ae8dc65bd325";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslashes.

```
var url = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wcf2\\wcf/attachments/5d/18-5dffacdfe6d2cf1db8dfabbb5b53ae8dc65bd325";
```

If the string is printed from PHP, you can use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to do the work for you.

```
$test = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wcf2\wcf/attachments/5d/18-...';
echo $test . "\n";
echo addslashes($test);

>> C:\xampp\htdocs\wcf2\wcf/attachments/5d/18-...
>> C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wcf2\\wcf/attachments/5d/18-...
```

#### Side Note

By the way, two things are incorrect with your approach:

1. The slashes in your string should all point the same way. If you want it to be used as a URL, use forward slashes *e.g.* `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17775495`
2. If you want to give the browser a URL that it can use to access some resource on your server, this URL cannot be a file path (such as `C:\xampp\htdocs\...`.) Instead, it has to be either relative to your site root, or an absolute URL (such as `http://dropbox.com/my/file.pdf`). Don't forget that a web user can only access files on your server through the web server.